# Update View automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, process

I have a TextBox which tells the status of a running application (lets say notepad). If notepad is running Text of TextBox is running and not running for other case.

```
public string ProcessStatus
{
    get 
    {
         IsProcessRunning("Notepad.exe")
              return "Running";
         return "Not Running";
    }
}
```

Now problem here is that view updates itself only once when it is launched. At that time if notepad is running it works fine. Now lets suppose I ran my application and notepad was not running then TextBox says not running. Now I launch notepad, now application is still saying not running as application has not updated the view. If I call notify of property changed event for the TextBox then it will say running. But I want here is that TextBox updates automatically.

The only solution what I am thinking right now is that I start a background process which keeps on updating `ProcessStatus`. But is this the right way? Is there any better way? Something like DirectoryWatcher for processes?

Comment: I think the culprit is the calling code. The UI thread is probably blocked by your polling mechanism or something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455873/how-to-detect-a-process-start-end-using-c-sharp-in-windows and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-sharp-process-monitor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` to check at regular intervals:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000); // checks every 10 seconds
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Start();

...

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do your checks here
    textbox.Text = ProcessStatus;
}
```

You can find out more about the `DispatcherTimer` class from the [DispatcherTimer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) page at MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the timer class to periodically run ProcessStatus, you can define the interval.

Answer (score 0):

On this other question [Can I Get Notified When Some Process Starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916141/can-i-get-notified-when-some-process-starts) there are two answers on how you can get notified if a process (e.g. Notepad.exe) starts. Both are neither ideal nor simple, I would probably stick to polling as Sheridan and NSmeef suggested.