# Is there a way to attach an event handler to the list of running processes in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, events, process

I'm currently writing a winforms application that is sensitive to programs being run in the background. At the moment I have a thread checking every second if the process I'm interested in has started/is still running, but I'm sure this would be much easier if I could just use an event to tell me when the user has opened/closed the application. Note that I am not starting the process manually within the program; the user has total control over that. Looking through the process documentation I don't see anything. Is there any way to hook into this?

Comment: You might find the answer here useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916141/can-i-get-notified-when-some-process-starts

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Process Monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/net-process-monitor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Events to track this.

Here is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var query = new EventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance isa \"Win32_Process\"");

    using (var eventWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(query))
    {
        eventWatcher.EventArrived += eventWatcher_EventArrived;
        eventWatcher.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        Console.ReadLine();
        eventWatcher.EventArrived -= eventWatcher_EventArrived;
        eventWatcher.Stop();
    }
}

static void eventWatcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var instanceDescription = e.NewEvent.GetPropertyValue("TargetInstance") as ManagementBaseObject;
        if(instanceDescription!=null)
        {
            var executablePath = instanceDescription.GetPropertyValue("ExecutablePath");
            if(executablePath!=null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Application {0} started", executablePath.ToString());
            }
         }
    }
    catch (ManagementException) { }
}
```

There are a lot of process attributes that can be received. Like Priority, Description, Command Line arguments, etc. You can look in *instanceDescription.Properties* for details.

Comment: That's very handy, nice and clean. And it shouldn't slow down the starting of new processes the way my solution might (if the hook is too slow).

Answer (score 3):

Well, at the very least, it should be possible to create a hook on the `CreateProcess` WinAPI method. You could even use that to prevent the process from starting at all (by simply returning `false` if you don't want the process to start). Of course, you'll have to make a hook on every method that can start a new process, but there's not all that many.

As Purrformance suggested, http://easyhook.codeplex.com/ is a great lib to easily create hooks from .NET.

Comment: I was going to answer something similar, but since you did it, here's a +1. Also, it migth be worth mentioning [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)